# Finding correlation of 4 variables/columns using R

Tags: r, statistics, correlation

I am trying to find the correlation between 4 columns of the dataset,

```
G = data$G_Score
H = data$COA
I = data$T_s
J = data$GP
cor(G,H,I,J)
```

But I am getting the below error:

```
invalid 'use' argument
```

I know it works with 2 arguments but my question is below:

Find the correlation between the "G_Score", "T_s", "GP" and the "COA". Any hint?

Comment: Can't do it like that, try `cor(data[,c("G_Score","COA","T_s","GP")]`.

Comment: It gives error incomplete expression

Comment: I forgot an `)` at the end.

Comment: oopps perfect, thank you

Comment: @user2974951 It also works without the comma .

Answer (score 0):

@user2974951 already provided a good, base R solution.  I will expand on it a bit.  Upvotes appreciated if this is helpful.

In your example, you made individual vector objects G, H, I, and J.  @user2974951 rightly showed these needed to be within the same dataframe for the cor() function to work properly for more than 2 vector objects, e.g. cor(G,H) would be fine but not cor(G,H,I).

If your data was originally stored as individual vectors G,H,I, and J, you could put them into a dataframe first like this:

```
cor(data.frame(G,H,I,J))
```

If you dislike typing all the quotation marks for the base R solution, you can use %>% and select as an alternate solution, like this:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% select(G_Score, COA, T_s, GP) %>% cor()
```